# How can I access locally stored datasets for ML models on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm trying to use AWS EC2's GPU to train deep learning models. My question is how ML practitioners would usually store datasets for training a model on EC2 (Are there best practices?). For now, I'd like to access datasets on my local PC but would it be possible? If so, could you point me a source or give me a direction?

Some specifics:

- Machine learning task: Image classification such as CNNs
- Data size: 1 million images (mostly 63*63) but I’m using sample datasets for research phase
- Training/predicting frequency: Not often (for research phase)

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too broad. Can you assist by making it more specific? For example, which Machine Learning system do you intend using? How big is your data? How often will you be retraining the system?